# Ability in QGIS modeler to just run a step or subsequent steps in a model

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

In the current QGIS LTR is it possible to just run one step or all subsequent steps in a model if the previous steps have all been run and are not changed?

Sometimes steps take hours to run so if they haven't changed, I'd like to just run a step for testing rather than the whole thing without having to split the model into multiple different models.

If you deactivate an upstream process then the downstream ones also get deactivated and if you disconnect it then you have add an input and delete this once tested -all of which are time consuming.

Comment: Would be good to have the ability quickly switch an input from 'output of the previous step' to a 'user specified' input. Currently I see the only way to achive this is to use child models that are split into logical steps and can be run indepdently or from a master model.